# Load an HTML Page (in same tab) stored within same folder by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

So there are html pages, **'login.html'** and **'register.html'** stored within same folder on my desktop.

when i open my **login.html** page it has a button when clicked should be redirected to **register.html** page.

[image: The Folder]

i have checked that the button event it self is working fine when button is pressed the event is fired (confirmed through alert method)

```
    document.getElementById('logIn').onclick= function(){
    window.location.href="login.html" // does not works 
    window.location.href="./login.html" // does not works 
    window.location.href("/login.html") // does not works 
    window.location ="login.html" // does not works 
    window.open("login.html")// open it but in a new tab (which i dont want)
    window.open("login.html","_self")// does not works 
}
```

also i am not using jquery for this project.

Comment: location.href is not a function .... you simply assign the url to it

Comment: that too not work is it because all my buttons are inside a form and i did not assigned any action to the form

Comment: Did you serve the file from a http server or just simple open it via the browser and navigate between the files from the file system (file://) proto in url ? 1) server the files via a webserver, 2) `window.location.href = "http://example.com/path";`

Comment: its on my windows/desktop.

Comment: @HassaanRaza That dosnt answer any of my questions...

Comment: anyways thanks for your time i have found out the problem, and posted the answer it was form action all along.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why those wouldn't work, but perhaps you can try this:
(basically, you create an anchor tag, set its properties, and click it)

```js
document.getElementById('logIn').onclick = function() {
  let loginAnchor = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(loginAnchor);
  loginAnchor.style.display = 'none';
  loginAnchor.href = 'login.html';
  loginAnchor.click();
}
```

For future reference, you should stay as consistent as reasonable with your string literals (single quote / double quote / template). Also, don't use `window` unnecessarily (unless it improves readability). Lastly, `location.href` is not a method, but a property whose value you should set.

Answer (score -1):

i found out the problem, form tag was preventing the page from loading a new one!
so i simply replaced form tag with a div tag.

**BEFORE**

```
<form>
//all buttons inside
</form>
```

**AFTER**

```
<div>
//all buttons inside
</div>
```

**Click Event of the Button:**

```
document.getElementById('logIn').onclick= function(){
    window.location.href ="login.html";
}
```

Comment: Thats terrible and double of the work. Decide for one way. Either user only the action defined in the form or only click event... but not both

Comment: you are right that comes up with a new problem, all button are now loading login.html, but if i do not use action form does not let any page load, what can i do? not use form?

Comment: Depends on what you want. I dont understand how i can help you or what you try to reach. A click on "submit" does a `GET` request on `login.html`, a click on "login" a (`GET`) redirect to `login.html` these override each other if its the same button. Not gonna mention that you are override your `GET` (query) parameters. What is your goal?!

Comment: i updated the answer, my goal was simple there was two button, button1 should load the login.html and button2 does something else other than loading the page (buttons are inside the form) and i have not used form before so dont know what to do.

Comment: my problem is now truly resolved but why the heck form was causing that issue? and can't we just tell the form to shut the hell and don't do anything problematic!